# PayPal IPN not received for Adaptive Payment from user to user

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm building a website where users can purchase digital goods that other users have posted for sale.  I want to use PayPal Adaptive Payments so that the money directly goes to the seller (not to me).

I have the payments working, but I'm not getting IPN messages unless I use my own PayPal account as the seller (receiver).  When any other PayPal account is the receiver my IPN URL doesn't get hit at all.

Can you tell me whether I should expect to get Instant Payment Notifications in this scenario,  why it might not be working, or any other way I can find out when the payment is completed?

**Update**

When I login to PayPal and look at IPN History I can see that it tried to send IPNs to me for the payments to other receivers, but they all got HTTP status code **403**.  I can also see when it tried to send me an IPN for the payment to myself - this one got HTTP status code 200.

I don't know why it would get a 403 response, because I don't have any kind of access control on that URL.  And I don't know why it would only get a 403 when the IPN is for a payment to someone else.

When I look in my web server logs I see PayPal trying to hit my IPN receiver and it mostly gets **404**, except the one case where the payment was to myself - this got a 200.

```
173.0.82.126 - - [23/Jun/2012:15:25:00 +1000] "POST /ajax/paypal/AdaptivePayments/ipn.php HTTP/1.0" 404 - "-" "-"
173.0.82.126 - - [23/Jun/2012:15:24:59 +1000] "POST /ajax/paypal/AdaptivePayments/ipn.php HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "-"
```

I'll check whether there is something in my Apache web server that might be rejecting the POSTs to the IPN receiver based on the body of POST.

Comment: I think I've solved this myself - it seems like it was related to having "/../" in my returnUrl and cancelUrl.  Maybe Apache was blocking the IPN messages because they contained "/../".  I'll investigate more and post an update tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it is definitely related to having "/../" in the returnUrl and cancelUrl.  I have solved the problem by removing the "/../" from the returnUrl and cancelUrl.  I didn't think these would be a problem because "/../" is used in the sample in [PayPal's Adaptive Payments PHP NVP SDK](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#adaptivepayments).  I assume it must be some security setting in Apache that is blocking POSTs with bodies containing "/../", but I haven't looked deeply into it.